# Wordpress Plugin Slider Revolution Error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I am unable to get rid of this following error. The error shows up after I activate the plugin.

```
Slider Revolution error: could not unzip into the revslider/public/assets/ folder, please make sure that this folder is writable.
```

I did chmod 777 to revslider/public/assets/ but with no use.

I also got this error in browser..

```
Revolution Slider Error: You have some jquery.js library include that comes after the revolution files js include.
This includes make eliminates the revolution slider libraries, and make it not work.
To fix it you can:
    1. In the Slider Settings -> Troubleshooting set option: Put JS Includes To Body option to true.
    2. Find the double jquery.js include and remove it.
```

I cannot go to Troubleshooting set option after going to slider settings as none of the links (including 'Problem Handlings') work on the right hand side (attached the screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same problem. I am not sure what cause this problem but I can share my workaround:

1. First you have to have FTP access to your WP folder
2. Deactivate Revolution Slider plugin
3. Use FTP and go to **revslider/public/assets/assets/svg/** and download **svg.zip** file to your PC.
4. Unzip **svg.zip**. Grab all unzipped content and put it in **uploads/revslider/assets/svg/** folder.(If in uploads/revslider folders assets and svg doesn't exist you have to create them manually).
5. Go to **revslider/inludes/framework/** open **base.class.php** file and edit function **public_folder_unzip()**:

**Old code**

```
 if($unzipfile === true){
 update_option('rs_public_version', RevSliderGlobals::SLIDER_REVISION); 
 }
 else{
 add_action('admin_notices', array('RevSliderBase', 'copy_notice'));
 }
```

**New code**

```
 if($unzipfile == true){
 update_option('rs_public_version', RevSliderGlobals::SLIDER_REVISION); 
 }
 else{
 add_action('admin_notices', array('RevSliderBase', 'copy_notice'));
 }
```

6. Save file changes.
7. Activate plugin.

Comment: i am also having this problem, but there is no such class called `public_folder_unzip()`to edit that equal signs. what shall i do guys?

Answer (score 9):

I found this happening today after updating the Autoptimize plugin. Turning off Javascript optimisation in the Autoptimize settings fixed the problem (though likely at the cost of some performance).

Comment: This the best answer .. when i disabled Autoptimize plugin revslider worked

Comment: Fixed my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is the best solution :

1. List item
2. Go to revolution slider on the dashboard
3. Select your slider causing the problem
4. go to param slider
5. Scroll to problem handlings on the right
6. Select Troubleshooting
7. set option:  Put JS Includes To Bodyoption to true.

That's it

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your theme and/or the Rev Slider plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue! And its not the "update everthing" problem. I loaded everything fresh in the latest version. Wordpress (4.5.2) and a theme appbox. And the slider is also directly loaded in the last version. The bad thing is, that the menu options of the rev slider in wordpress not working correctly... Thus, the solution prompted is not executable as the dropdown menu hiding the option for query, can't be accessed. Another side effect: the delete slider is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Batgor. Your method worked for me. Allow me to cosign to help others who encountered something slightly different.

My assets.zip file in the **./revslider/public/assets** folder was NOT unzipped. So i had to go in via SSH and unzip it first. Then once it blew up, I went into the **./revslider/includes/framework/base.class.php** file.

For those who have old man eyes like me - you have to remove the 3rd equals sign in

**if($unzipfile === true){**

so that you end up with

**if($unzipfile == true){**

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this today. Deactivating the plugin "Async Javascript" and turning off Javascript optimisation in the Autoptimize plugin settings fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the combo of

1. In the `Slider Settings` -> `Troubleshooting` set option: `Put JS Includes To Body option` to true.
2. Find the double `jquery.js` include and remove it. This was caused by auto optimize plugin. after I unchecked optimize JavaScript code that fixed it.

Comment: what do you mean by "Find the double jquery.js" ? how could i find it ?