# Duplicate Jquery in Wordpress with custom Theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress

so after 10 years I'm diving into Wordpress again.
I installed a theme that has its own jquery, altough wordpress comes with one.
That causes it to load 2 times which is unneccessary.

[image: Last two are both jqueury]

I stumbled upon some old posts about a dequeue function to dequeue the wp included jquery for frontend. Is this the way? Can someone help me, because I don't know much about backend stuff and if this works in 2023 with my version and my theme.

[Find the double jquery.js include and remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847322/find-the-double-jquery-js-include-and-remove-it)

Comment: If this were my project I'd get a different theme. WordPress coding standards call for using the version of jQuery embedded in core rather than including another version. You may be able to alter the theme code to fix this problem, but "you touch it, you own it" is no fun.